# Excel VBA for sending Mail through outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I need an excel VBA code, which when run, should ask for the cells which contain the email ID ( TO, Cc and Bcc) and then ask for the cells whose value should be the mail body in outlook.

Can anyone help me, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're basically asking us to build you something.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far to your question and specify which part you are having trouble with.

Comment: Have a look at Ron de Bruin's website.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @ Baksteen and Sirence... I am new to VBA....dont have any code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will help you get your desired results, it will prompt you to select a Range/Cell for To, CC, BCC, Subject & Email Body:

```
Sub SendEmail()

Set EmailTo = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select To", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailCC = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select CC", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailBCC = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select BCC", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailSubject = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Subject", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Body", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = EmailTo.Value
    .CC = EmailCC.Value
    .BCC = EmailBCC.Value
    .Subject = EmailSubject.Value
    .HTMLBody = EmailBody.Value
    .Display '.Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

The following will split multiple cells for the Body of the email:

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim c As Range, EmailTo As Range, EmailCC As Range, EmailSubject As Range, EmailBody As Range

Set EmailTo = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select To", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailCC = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select CC", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailBCC = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select BCC", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailSubject = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Subject", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Set EmailBody = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Body", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

For Each c In EmailBody
    BodyString = BodyString & "<br>" & c
    'Added <br> to separate each cell into a new line on the HTML email.
Next c

Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = EmailTo.Value
    .CC = EmailCC.Value
    .BCC = EmailBCC.Value
    .Subject = EmailSubject.Value
    .HTMLBody = BodyString
    .Display '.Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier.... can you help me once more for this code... Is it possible to select multiple cells for body of email..What changes need to be done in the code.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: @GyanMohan Updated my answer to reflect your comments, hope this helps...

Comment: Yes Xabier...This is the exact thing what I needed...Thanks a lot again for your help.